# Broken hyperlinks when converting .docx files to PDF via LibreOffice

Tags: pdf, docx, libreoffice, openoffice-writer, libreoffice-writer

I'm attempting to convert `.docx` files to `.pdf` via `soffice`, using the following command:

```
soffice --convert-to pdf input.docx --outdir <outdir>
```

The conversion succeeds without any error. However, the hyperlinks do not work. The hyperlinks in the file are relative links to other PDF files in the same directory.

The hyperlinks do not work - no matter what PDF reader I use, the hyperlinks aren't clickable.

I tried the following to narrow down my issue:

- Open the document in LibreOffice and “edit” the first hyperlink, open and close the dialog without doing anything.
- Save the .docx file in `LibreOffice`, and then run the headlesss conversion CLI via `soffice`.
- Observe that only the first hyperlink works - the one we “edited” without changing anything.

I opened the actual `.docx` internals, and found the `_rels` files were exactly identical. The only difference was that the hyperlink I “edited” had this additional tag in the `word/document.xml`:

```
<w:rStyle w:val="InternetLink" />
```

Some googling me found [this unanswered issue](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=146575). It appears that LibreOffice expects the InternetLink property to be present when converting hyperlinks to pdf.

My question is - how can I use `soffice` to convert the `.docx` to `.pdf` while retaining hyperlinks? Is there a code change I can make to the LibreOffice source code?

Comment: Works for me with LO 7.3.1.3 on Win10.